# How to let the resource annotations to be inherited by subclasses

Tags: java, annotations

For example, I have a superclass like below

```
public abstract class SuperServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @Resource(name = "varA")
  protected static String varA;
}
```

And the subclass

```
public class SubServlet extends SuperServlet {

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("varA: " + varA);
  }
}
```

I was planned to see the varA's value that I have set in the web.xml, but instead the value I got is null. So I think the resource annotation won't work in a scenario of inheritance like this.

Does anyone know how to make those annotation works on this?

Answer (score 0):

found it. I cannot use it on a static variable because the injection doesn't apply to a field that belong to the class, need to be a individual object.